# On which of the fingers is Petyr Baelish from/where are his lands?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In the books it is said they call him Littlefinger because his holdings are on the smallest of the Fingers. Which one is that (since his small castle does not appear on maps)? On the maps there are four. Is the smallest Finger the second most southern Finger or the second most northern one? I can't tell.

I don't know why I'm so interested. I think it's because Westeros is usually pretty detailed and then when it comes to this there is nothing. Is that a literary technique to indicate how insignificant his holdings are and how insignificant House Baelish would be if not for Petyr?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to A Wiki of Ice and Fire [Drearfort](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Drearfort), the seat of House Baelish, is located on the second most northern finger.

[image: Drearfort, the seat of House Baelish]

The wiki references George R. R. Martin's A World of Ice and Fire — A Game of Thrones Guide. [A companion guide available as a mobile app for iOS and Android](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/A_World_of_Ice_and_Fire). Application contains information about the people, houses, places, and maps of the Known World, was written by Elio M. García, Jr. and Linda Antonsson of Westeros.org **with input from George R. R. Martin**.

So yes, the location from wiki seams to be cannon.

Answer (score 4):

Surprisingly, according to [this](http://quartermaester.info/) website with an interactive map of the World of Ice and Fire, Littlefinger's "old flint tower" is *not* on the four most fingery Fingers at all, but here:

[image: that conniving little shit]

To find this image for yourself on the Quartermaester site: set your spoiler sensor to the end (or to as far as you've got, as long as it's further than the middle of aSoS2 when Littlefinger visits his ancestral home), select "Petyr Baelish" on the list of characters, and zoom in on the Fingers region.

---

As for canonicity, the Quartermaester map comes from [here](http://www.sermountaingoat.co.uk/map/) based on previous work from [here](http://www.cartographersguild.com/showthread.php?t=6683). The first of these links has an official endorsement, though not any sort of guarantee of accuracy, from George RR Martin himself.

Comment: I was just typing the same thing! But as a comment since I'm not sure what that site uses as its source. All I know is it's a composite from a bunch of different sources. Do you know?

Comment: @user568458 I don't know, and am trying to find out...

Comment: I checked the maps in my ebook copies of AFFC and ASOS, and it's not there

Comment: @user568458 I did a bit of poking around and have just edited.